# Stack overflow error with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, unity-game-engine, stack-overflow

I am currently developing a game in Unity and I decided to use a depth-first search to generate a maze.  This involves recursion, the dreaded beast, and I keep getting a stack overflow error even though I seem to have set up the recursion correctly.  I've been looking through it for a while, but I can't seem to find the error.

Here is the code:

```
private void MazeDigger(int[,] maze, int r, int c){

    int[] directions = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
    Shuffle(directions);

    for(int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++){

        switch(directions[i]){
        case 1:

            if(r-2 <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(maze[r-2, c] != 0)
            {
                maze[r-2, c] = 2;
                maze[r-1, c] = 2;
                MazeDigger(maze, r-2, c);
            }
            break;

        case 2:

            if(c+2 >= MazeWidth - 1)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(maze[r, c+2] != 0)
            {
                maze[r, c+2] = 2;
                maze[r, c+1] = 2;
                MazeDigger(maze, r, c+1);
            }
            break;

        case 3:

            if(r+2 >= MazeHeight - 1)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(maze[r+2, c] != 0)
            {
                maze[r+2, c] = 2;
                maze[r+1, c] = 2;
                MazeDigger(maze, r+2, c);
            }
            break;

        case 4:

            if(c-2 <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(maze[r, c-2] != 0)
            {
                maze[r, c-2] = 2;
                maze[r, c-1] = 2;
                MazeDigger(maze, r, c-2);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty simple really.  I create an array with four directions, I randomly shuffle through them and then use a for loop to run through the array.  There is a switch statement inside which will basically mark different points in the maze as being = 2.  This is because a different section of the code uses modulus to generate cubes at those locations.  Any help would be appreciated and please let me know if I did not provide enough information thank you!

Comment: Off the cuff, it sounds like it's just executing so many times that you're running out of memory in the stack.  Some tips to debug might include outputting how many iterations are being executed before it crashes.  Perhaps the exit conditions aren't working as you expect, and it's actually looping infinitely?  Confirming that the exit conditions are working appropriately is at least a good place to start, I think.

Comment: Ok so I had assumed it was looping infinitely because I had tested a 5x5 maze, which is quite small, and it wasn't generating that. I just tested a 3x3 maze though which works.  The highest I can generate is a 4x4.  This is supposed to work with 100x100 and much larger mazes.  I don't usually get any stack issues on this machine.  How is it overflowing so easily?

Comment: the subject is so meta! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no exit condition or you messed up the check.

You mark every visited cell with `2`, but you will visit it again if it is unequal to `0`. Never ending story :)

The 3x3 maze works, because every cell fails your border check and no recursion happens.
The 4x4 maze should already fail, but it may work for certain starting conditions.

Comment: You were correct, although for some reason a 4x4 would always work for me.  I fixed this by changing the condition of the if statements.  Thanks!